# Reversing certain subsequences of an array of integers

Tags: arrays, swift

**Problem Overview**

I have a list of items - basically a running list of a persons attendance

An attendance could be either - Free / Paid / Reset

Paid counts up 1, reset starts the next paid session at 1

**Such as**

Jan 1 (Paid)  >> 2

Jan 2 (Paid)  >> 1

Jan 7 (Free)  >> 0

Jan 8 (Free)  >> 0

Jan 12 (Reset)>> 0

Jan 20 (Paid) >> 4

Jan 21 (Paid) >> 3

Jan 26 (Paid) >> 2

Feb 6 (Free)  >> 0

Feb 8 (Paid)  >> 1

Feb 12 (Free) >> 0

**Examples**

```
enum AttendanceType {
    case paid, free, reset
}

let c: [AttendanceType] = [.paid, .paid, .paid]
// [3,2,1]

let d: [AttendanceType] = [.paid, .free, .paid, .paid, .paid]
// [1,0,3,2,1]

let a: [AttendanceType] = [.free, .paid, .free, .reset, .paid, .paid, .paid, .paid]
// [0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1]

let b: [AttendanceType] = [.reset, .paid, .free, .paid, .reset, .paid, .paid]
// [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I wonder if it might help if you explained the context?

Comment: @JoshCaswell will do

Comment: Maybe I don't get the explanation (or maybe it's besides the point) but it seems that consecutive numbers in the array will always be consecutive. In which case, why don't you just count down instead of up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as *an* answer:

```
func portionReverse(_ input: [Int]) -> [Int]
{
  var output: [Int] = []
  var subArray: [Int] = []

  input.forEach
  {
    if $0 == 0
    {
      output.append(contentsOf: subArray.reversed())
      output.append(0)
      subArray = []
    }
    else
    {
      subArray.append($0)
    }
  }
  output.append(contentsOf: subArray.reversed())

  return output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def subReverse(arr):
    result = []
    position = 0
    for index,item in enumerate(arr):
        if item == 0: position = index+1
        result.insert(position,item)
    return result

subReverse([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # [0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

[EDIT] I just realized this was a Swift question (not Python).  Here is the same function in Swift:

```
func subReverse(_ array:[Int]) -> [Int]
{
    var result   = [Int]()
    var position = 0
    for (index,item) in array.enumerated()
    {
        if item == 0 { position = index+1 }
        result.insert(item, at:min(position,result.count))
    }
    return result
}
subReverse([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) // [0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this - just wanted to know if there was something more elegant

```
extension Collection where Element == AttendanceType {

    var itemSort: [Int] {

        var output = [Int]()
        var current = 0

        self.reversed().forEach { item in
            switch item {
            case .free:
                output.append(0)
            case .paid:
                current += 1
                output.append(current)
            case .reset:
                current = 0
                output.append(current)
            }
        }
        return output.reversed()
    }
}
```